# How to use ngx-permission in parent and children component at same time in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using ngx-permission for permission management. After login I redirected to dashboard.

I have created user layout component with header sidebar and footer. Here loaded the dashboard component as children. I am able to get the permission in userlayout component. So I have used the *ngxPermissionsOnly directive in template.

But after logout, At second time, login form submit event not working.

```
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, NgxPermissionsGuard],
    component: UserLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: AppFrontRoutes.DASHBOARD,
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Dashboard',
          permissions: { only: [AppPermissions.LOGGED_IN], redirectTo: AppFrontRoutes.LOGIN }
        },
      },
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

for children you have to use **canActivateChild** and you have to clear permissions after logout, don't forget to load the after login and inside UserLayoutComponent

```
{
 path: '',
 canActivateChild: [AuthGuard, NgxPermissionsGuard],
 component: UserLayoutComponent,
 children: [
   {
    path: AppFrontRoutes.DASHBOARD,
    component: DashboardComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Dashboard',
      permissions: { only: [AppPermissions.LOGGED_IN], redirectTo: AppFrontRoutes.LOGIN }
    }
   }
 ]
},
```